# Agregar un div cuando se recorren tres elementos dentro de un map() en React

Tags: reactjs, lista

lo que quiero lograr es imprimir filas con 3 elementos columna

```
<div className="fila">
      <div className="columna"/>
      <div className="columna"/>
      <div className="columna"/>
 </div>
```

obtengo el arreglo Inmue que contiene todas las columnas y recorro sus elementos

```
 {Inmue.map((inm, i) => {
       return <div datos={inm} className="columna"/>
      })}
```

entonces el problema es que si agrego el elemento fila este se añade cada vez que recorro una columna  , y lo que quiero es que una fila contenga 3 columnas

intente esto pero marca error al no cerrar un div

```
if((i+1)% 3 ==0)
      return (</div>
        <div className="flex flex-row pb-6">)
```

okey no estoy casado con map cualquier sugerencia de como hacerlo es bien recibida

**al final quedo asi**

```
{Inmue &&
        [...Array(Math.ceil(Inmue.length / 3))].map((fila, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="flex flex-row pb-6" key={i}>
              {Inmue.slice(i * 3, i * 3 + 3).map((columna, j) => {
                return <div key={j}>{j}</div>;
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
          [...Array(Math.ceil(randArray.length / 3))].map((fila, f) => {
            return (
              <div key=f{f} className='fila'>
                {
                  Inmue.slice(f*3,f*3+3).map((col,c) => {
                    return <div key=c{c} datos={col} className='columna'></div>
                  })
                }
              </div>
            )
          })
```

Comment: pues muchas gracias amigo si funciono , solo me quedo duda por que al llamar a slice de (0,3) , me regresa 3 elementos en vez de 4

Comment: array.slice(start,end)   regresa los elementos desde start hasta end pero sin incluir el ultimo.. es decir,, [start,end}